# Call ImagePicker Function

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to call this function from another part of my view controller code, but can't figure out how to pass in the `picker` and `editingInfo`. I have the image stored elsewhere. So to restate, how would I call this function from another part of the code like `viewDidLoad()`? I'm coding in Swift 2. Thanks for any help!

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
// Do something with images here...
}
```

Comment: You don't call that method. The `UIImagePickerController` calls that method when the user selects an image.

Comment: See comment below please.

Answer (score 0):

You would *never* call that function. It is a delegate method. You *implement* and the runtime calls *you*.

Comment: My issue is that a conversation may or may not have been setup when this method is called. When it's called I check for that. If the conversation hasn't been created yet, I want to create it, then call this again. The conversation cannot be created before hand unfortunately.